# How can I mark coordinates from a Google sheet on a sidebar map? -- Map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-sheets, google-maps-api-3

Here's my situation: I have a google sheet of coordinates that I want to map on a simple map. This map I want to put on a sidebar within google sheets. It will get more complex as I go but I'm struggling with the basics.

So I want to import the coordinates of C2:D2 into my HTML so I used this: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initMap).selectAddress().

It seems to work for most things but when I use it for the coordinates of the marker, nothing no marker shows up. If I replace
 "var lat = CoordArray[0]; var lng =  CoordArray[1];" 
with
 "var lat =51.0366961; var lng = -114.0744921;" 
in the HTML, the marker shows up.

Even if I make "var CoordArray= [51.0366961,-114.0744921]" in the JS code, the marker still doesn't show. So the problem has something to do with transferring the information between the two pages.

I just want an interactive map sidebar that's based on coordinates from the sheet that I can kind of understand and modify.

So my JS code page looks like this:

```
     function mapSidebar(){

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Map.html')
                        .setTitle("Map Sidebar");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function selectAddress(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("maps?");

  var CoordArray = sheet.getRange("C2:D2").getValues(); // C2:D2 = 51.0366961,-114.0744921

  return CoordArray;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Html page (Map.html) looks like this:

and yes, I replaced put my API key in the 'https://maps.googleapis.com/' link

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

function initMap(CoordArray) {
var lat = CoordArray[0];
var lng =  CoordArray[1];

  var markerPosition = {lat: lat,lng: lng}

  var  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center:{lat: 51.0366961,lng: -114.0744921},
            zoom: 8,
         });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: markerPosition, map: map});

}
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initMap).selectAddress();

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: No errors that could see, the marker just doesn't appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you may be having an issue with the `Range.getValues()` method in your code. This method returns a 2D array indexed by rows, then by columns.

Try in your `initMap()` function to get the "lat" and "lng" like so:

```js
function initMap(CoordArray) {
    var lat = CoordArray[0][0];
    var lng = CoordArray[0][1];

    var markerPosition = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 51.0366961,
            lng: -114.0744921
        },
        zoom: 8,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPosition,
        map: map
    });

}
```

---

**References:**

- Apps script docs [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Thanks so much, not sure how I missed that after all this time!